# Universal Apps Live Tiles

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, live-tile

I have reached the stage in my universal windows app where I would like to create a live tile.

The articles I have read suggest that you should create a BackgroundTask in a separate assembly to keep the footprint small, so I have created a new portable class library for this purpose.

There are a number of templates available for your live tile, some are not supported on windows phone and some are not supported on windows store apps.

The problem I have is, if I want to create different live tiles for windows phone and windows store platforms, I cannot tell which platform it is running on because the portable class library I have created don't have anyway of identifying this.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After giving this considerable thought I've decided that the best answer is to create 2 versions of the BackgroundTask, one for Windows Phone and one for Windows Store, and then register the correct one when your main app is run.